# .net is not starting the tasks as i order it - what is the logic of starting new tasks

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, threadpool, multitasking

After working a while noticed that, even if you spawn 1000 tasks, they don't start immediately. So basically even if i start 1000 tasks, 100 of them running and 900 of them waiting to run.

So my question is, how are they begining to start ?
How .net determines when to start running task or make it waittorun ?
What methodolgy i can follow to start them immediately ?
I want to have certain number of task/thread running all the time.

If i use threads instead of tasks would they start running immediately or .net will start them as it please like tasks ?

Question may not be very clear, so please ask me to clarify.

Basically i am spawning 1000 (keeping this number spawned. when 1 task completed starting another task) tasks but only 125 of them `Running` and 875 of them `WaitingToRun` :)

this is how i start task

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            startCheckingProxies();
        });
```

c# wpf 4.5

Comment: How do you "spawn" those "tasks" exactly? What is your code?

Comment: Tasks are meant as independent blocks: the TPL will run them as it sees fit.  It may be more efficient to run them in blocks of 100 vs. trying to parallelize all of them.

Comment: @ShadowWizard added code block to see how i do.

Comment: @Joe yes i also noticed TPL does that :) but i want to override it if possible. Is that possible ?

Comment: That's basically counter to what the TPL is trying to do. Tasks are fairly abstract; if you are trying to force parallelization that is more of an implementation detail that is outside the scope of that abstraction.  Just use threads in that case, but understand the resource strain that may put on your system.

Comment: The answer is             ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10000, 10000);
            ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(10000, 10000); and nobody gave this simple answer

Comment: If your company had four vans and four drivers and I handed you a thousand packages to deliver, would you start delivering all of them at the same time? Of course not. You'd deliver as many as you could efficiently at once, and make the rest wait. How long do they wait? Until there is a driver and a van available.

Comment: Your "solution" of messing with the thread pool will make things worse, not better. Suppose you had four vans and ten thousand drivers, and again, a thousand packages to deliver. Now you're handing one package to each of 1000 drivers, paying the salaries of the other 9000 drivers who are idle, and a thousand drivers are taking turns each driving a van for a block. The whole point of task based asynchrony is *to prevent you from doing that*. Don't abuse the system.

Comment: @EricLippert i tried and it definitely made better :) now i am able to harvest faster. I also have enough resources but .net doesnt know it. I have 850 MB per second I/O write and read and 50 mbit fiber connection. Anyway right now svchost exe is getting 1 core 100% :) I need to find how can i make svchost run with multiple cores or run multiple svchost network exe :)

Comment: are your tasks io bound or processor bound?

Comment: @EricLippert my tasks are network bound

Comment: Well then there is your problem. By default the scheduler assumes that you're creating processor-bound tasks. You shouldn't be making lots of threads at all; you should be scheduling the I/O completion thread to call your main thread back when the network job completes. You can do this with a very small number of threads.  Remember, threads are *insanely expensive*; treat them the same way you'd treat hiring a new employee. You don't hire one letter carrier per envelope delivered.

Comment: @EricLippert lol i am not that much ignorant. if threads were cpu expensive i already would know i should not compose many threads. this is why i have been asking. TPL is not smart enough.

Comment: No, it's not that threads are CPU expensive; it is precisely the cases where threads are *NOT* cpu-expensive that you don't want to create a lot of them!  The last thing you want to do is make ten thousand threads each of which takes up 0.01% of a CPU because that's *ten gigabytes of stack space in the swap file*. If you have lots of non-cpu-bound tasks then do not give them to lots of threads. Give them to *one* thread that can handle the completions of *all* of the tasks.

Comment: @EricLippert Lippert how would you achieve with 1 thread to harvest 100 urls from internet at the same time ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: I remind you that this is a *question and answer site*. If that is actually your question then *post a new question*.

Comment: But more generally, I think you are trying to optimize for the wrong thing. You have a network-bound problem and you are trying to increase your cpu utilization. That is exactly the opposite of what you should be doing; if the problem is network bound then you should be trying to *minimize* your cpu utilization and max out your network card. If your problem is actually cpu bound then let the Task Parallel Library do its job; it is good at scheduling your cpus. If your problem is not cpu bound then the TPL is not the right tool; use the asynchronous http client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about `Task` objects, they are run on top of the thread pool, so they will not all start immediately by running each on a separate thread. Instead, the limited number of tasks will initially be started on threads coming from the pool, and then the threads will be reused to run next tasks and so on.

Of course, this is just a high-level description, the logic behind is more complex and implements lot of optimizations.

You can find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx)

You can also start tasks with the overload of `StartNew` which lets you [tweak options and scheduler settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781658.aspx). Note, however, that running on a large number of threads will likely result in worse performance. Thread creation and context switching have significant costs, and running thousands of threads will, IMO, backfire.

Answer (score 5):

Tasks are really just threads under the hood.

There is a limit to how much benefit you can get by spawning new threads.  Each thread has some overhead, so at some point, the overhead is going to exceed the benefit of spawning a new thread.  If you leave the spawning of those tasks to the Framework, it is going to decide for itself how many threads it's going to run at once, and it's going to make that decision based on how much productivity it thinks it can get from those threads.

I'm pretty sure that optimal number is not going to be a thousand; I've written Windows Services where the optimal number of threads to run at the same time is the number of cores in the machine (in my case, it was 4).

Comment: thanks a lot for answer. can i override this thread pool thing ? i want to decide myself instead of netframework.

Comment: You think you know better than the Thread Pool? :)  Sure you can, just spin up your own threads.

Comment: i don't think but i want to try :)

Comment: for example it was 125 when i first opened this thread and now 224 is running :)

Comment: If you really want to run that many threads you are probably better off running your program on your GPU (your graphics card). If you have an NVIDIA can you can look up the CUDA library; else you may want to check out OpenGL.

Comment: A lot of optimizations and tricks (e.g. work stealing) is performed behind the curtains, so it won't be easy. besides, you can specify concurrency level and other options on `TaskScheduler`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321282.aspx

Comment: currently cpu usage is very low. running task count keep getting increased by the time also. right now 301 tasks running. but i want it to set amount i want :) isn't that possible ? also my cpu is 8 cores @ 4.5 GHZ

Comment: running thread count increased to 415. it is increasing as the time passes. but i want to start with that count :) isn't that possible ?

Comment: Tasks are not threads. Tasks are like assignments and threads are like workers; you can have a million tasks and only one thread; tasks do not automatically entail multiple threads.

Comment: @EricLippert yes i learnt that but in my scenario almost every task gets its own thread. I am checking from task manager.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: In your scenario every task is getting its own thread because you are telling the task parallel library that *every task is CPU bound*. The TPL is trying to assign threads to tasks so as to most efficiently use the processors, but if you are lying to it about whether those tasks are CPU bound then it is not going to do a good job and it is going to allocate way too many threads. You're not using the right tool for the job here; use the TPL when you have a bunch of CPU-intensive work that needs to be scheduled to various processors.